# How to make my navbar load above my element's animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, navbar, fixed

i have a problem in developping my portfolio.
i made a fixed navbar who start transparent and after scrolling it change to black background.
my problem is with a box in a section when i add animation after hovering, 
it scales in both X and Y and it appears above the navbar that i made.
i want the navbar to have the hightest priority 
i tried z_index but it didnt work

this is the css of the navbar

```
.navbar-custom{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgb(3, 3, 3, 0);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

and this is the css of the Box

```
.skill{
    text-align: center;
    width: 16.6%;
    height: 40vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.skill:hover{
    animation-name: skillbox;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes skillbox{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, sarafi won't correctly render RGB opacity, unless you use rgba(). Not a lot of people use safari on desktop, but a lot of iphone users who by default use safari. I realize this isn't relevant to your question here, but looking through, hoped I would save you the frustrations I've had with this.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is the solution, but z-index does not work on static elements, which is the default position of elements. When you tried the z-index solution you probably forgot to set the `.skill` element to position relative.

```css
.navbar-custom{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    padding-right: 50px;
    height:50px;
    // This was added. The other styles I added were just for visualisation purposes.
    z-index:2;
}
.skill{
    text-align: center;
    width: 16.6%;
    height: 40vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:pink;
    margin-top:50px;
    // This was added. The other styles I added were just for visualisation purposes.
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.skill:hover{
    animation-name: skillbox;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes skillbox{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-custom"></div>
<div class="skill"></div>
```